# How to solve what(): std::bad_alloc error with cleverhans on GPU

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, conv-neural-network, cleverhans

After training this neural network `Input -> [[Conv2D->relu]*2 -> MaxPool2D -> Dropout]*2 -> Flatten -> Dense -> Dropout -> Output` on MNIST data using keras I am trying to generate adversarial examples using cleverhans. However I am always getting some memory error:

```
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::bad_alloc'
    what():  std::bad_alloc
Aborted
```

Looks like I ran out of memory but this is log from script I used for tracking memory while application crashed:

```
      date     time           total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
2019-10-17 22:35:16           64302        2825       56795         409        4681       60412
2019-10-17 22:35:16           64302        2826       56795         409        4681       60412
2019-10-17 22:35:16           64302        2827       56793         409        4681       60411
2019-10-17 22:35:16           64302        2827       56793         409        4681       60410
2019-10-17 22:35:16           64302        2827       56793         409        4681       60410
2019-10-17 22:35:16           64302        2827       56794         409        4681       60411
2019-10-17 22:35:16           64302        2826       56794         409        4681       60412
2019-10-17 22:35:16           64302        2827       56793         409        4681       60410
2019-10-17 22:35:16           64302        2827       56793         409        4681       60411
2019-10-17 22:35:16           64302        2826       56793         409        4682       60412
2019-10-17 22:35:16           64302        2827       56790         409        4684       60410
2019-10-17 22:35:16           64302        2827       56790         409        4684       60410
2019-10-17 22:35:16           64302        2827       56790         409        4684       60411
2019-10-17 22:35:16           64302        2828       56789         409        4684       60410
2019-10-17 22:35:16           64302        2828       56790         409        4684       60410
2019-10-17 22:35:16           64302        2827       56791         409        4684       60411
2019-10-17 22:35:16           64302        2827       56791         409        4684       60411
2019-10-17 22:35:16           64302        2827       56790         409        4684       60410
2019-10-17 22:35:16           64302        2828       56790         409        4684       60410
2019-10-17 22:35:16           64302        2827       56790         409        4684       60410
2019-10-17 22:35:16           64302        2828       56789         409        4684       60409
2019-10-17 22:35:16           64302        2828       56786         409        4687       60410
2019-10-17 22:35:16           64302        2828       56786         409        4687       60410
2019-10-17 22:35:16           64302        2828       56786         409        4687       60409
2019-10-17 22:35:16           64302        2828       56786         409        4687       60410
2019-10-17 22:35:16           64302        2829       56785         409        4687       60409
2019-10-17 22:35:16           64302        2828       56786         409        4687       60409
2019-10-17 22:35:16           64302        2829       56785         409        4687       60409
2019-10-17 22:35:16           64302        2829       56785         409        4687       60409
2019-10-17 22:35:16           64302        2830       56785         409        4687       60408
2019-10-17 22:35:16           64302        2829       56785         409        4687       60409
2019-10-17 22:35:16           64302        2830       56784         409        4687       60408
2019-10-17 22:35:16           64302        2830       56784         409        4687       60408
2019-10-17 22:35:16           64302        2830       56784         409        4687       60407
2019-10-17 22:35:16           64302        2830       56784         409        4687       60408
2019-10-17 22:35:16           64302        2830       56784         409        4687       60408
2019-10-17 22:35:16           64302        2830       56784         409        4687       60408
2019-10-17 22:35:16           64302        2830       56784         409        4687       60408
2019-10-17 22:35:16           64302        2830       56785         409        4687       60408
2019-10-17 22:35:16           64302        2830       56784         409        4687       60408
2019-10-17 22:35:16           64302        2829       56785         409        4687       60409
2019-10-17 22:35:16           64302        2831       56783         409        4687       60407
2019-10-17 22:35:16           64302        2831       56783         409        4687       60407
2019-10-17 22:35:16           64302        2830       56784         409        4687       60407
2019-10-17 22:35:16           64302        2830       56784         409        4687       60407
2019-10-17 22:35:16           64302        2830       56784         409        4687       60408
2019-10-17 22:35:16           64302        2831       56783         409        4687       60407
2019-10-17 22:35:16           64302        2831       56783         409        4687       60407
2019-10-17 22:35:16           64302        2831       56783         409        4687       60407
2019-10-17 22:35:16           64302        2830       56784         409        4687       60408
2019-10-17 22:35:16           64302        2830       56784         409        4687       60408
2019-10-17 22:35:16           64302        2831       56783         409        4687       60407
2019-10-17 22:35:16           64302        2831       56783         409        4687       60407
2019-10-17 22:35:16           64302        2830       56784         409        4687       60408
2019-10-17 22:35:16           64302        2830       56784         409        4687       60408
2019-10-17 22:35:16           64302        2830       56784         409        4687       60408
2019-10-17 22:35:16           64302        2830       56784         409        4687       60408
2019-10-17 22:35:16           64302        2829       56785         409        4687       60409
2019-10-17 22:35:16           64302        2829       56785         409        4687       60408
2019-10-17 22:35:16           64302        2830       56784         409        4687       60408
2019-10-17 22:35:16           64302        2830       56784         409        4687       60408
2019-10-17 22:35:16           64302        2830       56784         409        4687       60408
2019-10-17 22:35:16           64302        2830       56784         409        4687       60407
2019-10-17 22:35:16           64302        2831       56783         409        4687       60407
2019-10-17 22:35:16           64302        2830       56784         409        4687       60407
2019-10-17 22:35:16           64302        2830       56784         409        4687       60408
2019-10-17 22:35:16           64302        2830       56784         409        4687       60407
2019-10-17 22:35:16           64302        2831       56783         409        4687       60407
2019-10-17 22:35:16           64302        2831       56783         409        4687       60407
2019-10-17 22:35:16           64302        2832       56782         409        4687       60406
2019-10-17 22:35:16           64302        2831       56783         409        4687       60406
2019-10-17 22:35:16           64302        2831       56783         409        4687       60407
2019-10-17 22:35:16           64302        2830       56784         409        4687       60407
2019-10-17 22:35:16           64302        2831       56783         409        4687       60407
2019-10-17 22:35:16           64302        2831       56783         409        4687       60407
2019-10-17 22:35:16           64302        2831       56783         409        4687       60407
2019-10-17 22:35:16           64302        2831       56783         409        4687       60407
2019-10-17 22:35:16           64302        2831       56783         409        4687       60407
2019-10-17 22:35:16           64302        2832       56782         409        4687       60406
2019-10-17 22:35:16           64302        2832       56782         409        4687       60406
2019-10-17 22:35:16           64302        2841       56773         409        4687       60397
2019-10-17 22:35:16           64302        2849       56765         409        4687       60389
2019-10-17 22:35:16           64302        2857       56757         409        4687       60381
2019-10-17 22:35:16           64302        2865       56749         409        4687       60373
2019-10-17 22:35:16           64302        2874       56740         409        4687       60364
2019-10-17 22:35:16           64302        2882       56732         409        4687       60356
2019-10-17 22:35:16           64302        2890       56724         409        4687       60348
2019-10-17 22:35:16           64302        2900       56714         409        4687       60338
2019-10-17 22:35:16           64302        2908       56706         409        4687       60330
2019-10-17 22:35:16           64302        2916       56698         409        4687       60322
2019-10-17 22:35:16           64302        2924       56691         409        4687       60314
2019-10-17 22:35:16           64302        2932       56683         409        4687       60306
2019-10-17 22:35:16           64302        2939       56675         409        4687       60299
2019-10-17 22:35:16           64302        2947       56667         409        4687       60290
2019-10-17 22:35:16           64302        2957       56657         409        4687       60281
2019-10-17 22:35:16           64302        2970       56644         409        4687       60268
2019-10-17 22:35:16           64302        2986       56628         409        4687       60251
2019-10-17 22:35:16           64302        3003       56611         409        4687       60235
2019-10-17 22:35:16           64302        3021       56593         409        4687       60217
2019-10-17 22:35:16           64302        3038       56576         409        4687       60200
2019-10-17 22:35:16           64302        3053       56561         409        4687       60184
2019-10-17 22:35:16           64302        3070       56543         409        4687       60167
2019-10-17 22:35:16           64302        2959       56655         409        4687       60279
2019-10-17 22:35:16           64302        2958       56656         409        4687       60280
2019-10-17 22:35:16           64302        2958       56655         409        4687       60280
2019-10-17 22:35:17           64302        2958       56655         409        4687       60280
2019-10-17 22:35:17           64302        2958       56655         409        4687       60279
2019-10-17 22:35:17           64302        2958       56656         409        4687       60280
2019-10-17 22:35:17           64302        2958       56655         409        4687       60279
2019-10-17 22:35:17           64302        2959       56655         409        4687       60279
2019-10-17 22:35:17           64302        2958       56655         409        4687       60279
2019-10-17 22:35:17           64302        2957       56656         409        4687       60280
2019-10-17 22:35:17           64302        2957       56657         409        4687       60281
2019-10-17 22:35:17           64302        2957       56657         409        4687       60281
2019-10-17 22:35:17           64302        2957       56657         409        4687       60281
2019-10-17 22:35:17           64302        2957       56657         409        4687       60281
2019-10-17 22:35:17           64302        3047       56567         409        4687       60191
2019-10-17 22:35:17           64302        3107       56507         409        4687       60131
2019-10-17 22:35:17           64302        3159       56455         409        4687       60079
2019-10-17 22:35:17           64302        3233       56381         409        4687       60005
2019-10-17 22:35:17           64302        3281       56333         409        4687       59957
2019-10-17 22:35:17           64302        3343       56271         409        4687       59895
2019-10-17 22:35:17           64302        3399       56215         409        4687       59839
2019-10-17 22:35:17           64302        3463       56151         409        4687       59775
2019-10-17 22:35:17           64302        3521       56093         409        4687       59717
2019-10-17 22:35:17           64302        3567       56047         409        4687       59671
2019-10-17 22:35:17           64302        3621       55993         409        4687       59617
2019-10-17 22:35:17           64302        3673       55940         409        4687       59565
2019-10-17 22:35:17           64302        3739       55874         409        4687       59499
2019-10-17 22:35:17           64302        3797       55816         409        4687       59441
2019-10-17 22:35:17           64302        3854       55760         409        4687       59384
2019-10-17 22:35:17           64302        3912       55702         409        4687       59326
2019-10-17 22:35:17           64302        3968       55646         409        4687       59270
2019-10-17 22:35:17           64302        4028       55586         409        4687       59210
2019-10-17 22:35:17           64302        4092       55522         409        4687       59146
2019-10-17 22:35:17           64302        4144       55470         409        4687       59094
2019-10-17 22:35:17           64302        4196       55418         409        4687       59042
2019-10-17 22:35:17           64302        4260       55354         409        4687       58978
2019-10-17 22:35:17           64302        4318       55295         409        4687       58920
2019-10-17 22:35:17           64302        4372       55241         409        4687       58866
2019-10-17 22:35:17           64302        4430       55183         409        4687       58808
2019-10-17 22:35:17           64302        4493       55121         409        4687       58745
2019-10-17 22:35:17           64302        4547       55067         409        4687       58691
2019-10-17 22:35:17           64302        4605       55009         409        4687       58633
2019-10-17 22:35:17           64302        4667       54947         409        4687       58571
2019-10-17 22:35:17           64302        4721       54893         409        4687       58517
2019-10-17 22:35:17           64302        4779       54835         409        4687       58459
2019-10-17 22:35:17           64302        4835       54779         409        4687       58403
2019-10-17 22:35:17           64302        4895       54718         409        4687       58343
2019-10-17 22:35:17           64302        4951       54662         409        4687       58287
2019-10-17 22:35:17           64302        5013       54600         409        4687       58225
2019-10-17 22:35:17           64302        5072       54542         409        4687       58166
2019-10-17 22:35:17           64302        5130       54484         409        4687       58108
2019-10-17 22:35:17           64302        5184       54430         409        4687       58054
2019-10-17 22:35:17           64302        5248       54366         409        4687       57990
2019-10-17 22:35:17           64302        5306       54308         409        4687       57932
2019-10-17 22:35:17           64302        5366       54248         409        4687       57872
2019-10-17 22:35:17           64302        5424       54190         409        4687       57814
2019-10-17 22:35:17           64302        5482       54132         409        4687       57756
2019-10-17 22:35:17           64302        5540       54074         409        4687       57698
2019-10-17 22:35:17           64302        5588       54026         409        4687       57650
2019-10-17 22:35:17           64302        5652       53962         409        4687       57586
2019-10-17 22:35:17           64302        5706       53908         409        4687       57532
2019-10-17 22:35:17           64302        5764       53850         409        4687       57474
2019-10-17 22:35:17           64302        5812       53801         409        4687       57426
2019-10-17 22:35:17           64302        5876       53737         409        4687       57362
2019-10-17 22:35:17           64302        5928       53685         409        4687       57310
2019-10-17 22:35:17           64302        5985       53629         409        4687       57253
2019-10-17 22:35:17           64302        6043       53571         409        4687       57195
2019-10-17 22:35:17           64302        6103       53511         409        4687       57135
2019-10-17 22:35:17           64302        6157       53457         409        4687       57081
2019-10-17 22:35:17           64302        6211       53403         409        4687       57027
2019-10-17 22:35:17           64302        6267       53347         409        4687       56971
2019-10-17 22:35:17           64302        6327       53287         409        4687       56911
2019-10-17 22:35:17           64302        6383       53231         409        4687       56855
2019-10-17 22:35:17           64302        6437       53177         409        4687       56801
2019-10-17 22:35:17           64302        6495       53119         409        4687       56743
2019-10-17 22:35:17           64302        6563       53051         409        4687       56675
2019-10-17 22:35:17           64302        6613       53000         409        4687       56625
2019-10-17 22:35:17           64302        6671       52942         409        4687       56567
2019-10-17 22:35:17           64302        6723       52890         409        4687       56514
2019-10-17 22:35:17           64302        6771       52842         409        4687       56466
2019-10-17 22:35:17           64302        6831       52782         409        4687       56406
2019-10-17 22:35:17           64302        6882       52732         409        4687       56356
2019-10-17 22:35:17           64302        6934       52680         409        4687       56304
2019-10-17 22:35:17           64302        6982       52632         409        4687       56256
2019-10-17 22:35:17           64302        6981       52633         409        4687       56257
2019-10-17 22:35:17           64302        6886       52727         409        4687       56352
2019-10-17 22:35:17           64302        6809       52805         409        4687       56429
2019-10-17 22:35:17           64302        6720       52894         409        4687       56518
2019-10-17 22:35:17           64302        6614       53000         409        4687       56624
2019-10-17 22:35:17           64302        5345       54268         409        4687       57892
2019-10-17 22:35:17           64302        3943       55670         409        4687       59294
2019-10-17 22:35:17           64302        2482       57131         409        4687       60755
2019-10-17 22:35:17           64302        1894       57719         409        4687       61344
2019-10-17 22:35:17           64302        1497       58117         409        4687       61741
2019-10-17 22:35:17           64302        1134       58480         409        4687       62104
2019-10-17 22:35:17           64302         696       58918         409        4687       62542
2019-10-17 22:35:17           64302         574       59040         409        4687       62664
2019-10-17 22:35:17           64302         532       59082         409        4687       62706
2019-10-17 22:35:17           64302         532       59082         409        4687       62706
2019-10-17 22:35:17           64302         528       59086         409        4687       62710
2019-10-17 22:35:17           64302         528       59086         409        4687       62710
```

Here is the script:

```
#!/bin/bash -e

echo "      date     time $(free -m | grep total | sed -E 's/^    (.*)/\1/g')"  >> memory.log
while true; do
    echo "$(date '+%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S') $(free -m | grep Mem: | sed 's/Mem://g')"  >> memory.log
done
```

Can anyone help me find out what is the problem. Thanks.

Comment: Are you running on a GPU?

Comment: @TheGuywithTheHat if I am correct I am using GPU. I've used this lines of code to force GPU:
```
from keras import backend as K
,
K.tensorflow_backend._get_available_gpus()
``` is there a way hov to verify I am using GPU?

Comment: Run `nvidia-smi` while your code is doing its thing, you should see high `Memory-Usage` and `GPU-Util`.

Comment: looks like gpu is not in use: "No running processes found"